# Splitting an array of numbers and non-numbers into two separate arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, numbers

I'm very new to javascript and I'm trying to create a function that takes a mixed input of numbers and then loops through the array in order to sort them into two newer arrays so I can manipulate them further.

So if I have an input of 
1,a,2,b,3,c,4,d,

I want to make two new arrays of 
1,2,3,4 and a,b,c,d

So far I've been able to split the input string at the comma, so that I now have

1a2b3c4d

all I need to be able to do now is just separate the numbers and non-numbers. I was thinking of using two loops: one that checks

if(isNan.array[n] == True )

and then trying to find a way to store the letters into a variable using the loop and then using another loop to do so for the numbers using another if function.

Is this how I should do it, and do you have any advice on how to go about it?

Edit:

I now have this code to check for letters:

```
if (isNaN(splitResult[L])) {
        for (i = 0; i < splitResult; i++) {
            letterArray.add(splitResult[L]);
            L = L + 1
```

When I try to output the results to a box to count letters (using the variable L), nothing shows up. I doubt I've made a new array

Comment: Why loop twice? Do an `if(NaN...) letterArray.add(array[i]); else numArray.add(array[i]);`

Comment: You should try it first....then if it isn't working as expected ask questions here showing the code you are using

Comment: Use `arrayName.forEach(functionName)` and to add new item in array in JavaScript you use "push" not "add" so it will be `letterArray.push(item)`. you can check the forEach example here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp  Also isNan(item) is going to return a Boolean so you don't need equate it with true or false you can simply use `if(isNan(item)) {}`

Comment: 'Cause I'm extremely new to this; I can't even identify the loop in what you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

just for completion, split the string into array first :)

```
let yourString = '1a2b3c4d';
let yourArray = yourString.split('');
let letterArray = [];
let numberArray = [];
yourArray.forEach(item => {
  if(isNaN(item) && typeof item === 'string'){
    letterArray.push(item);
  }
  else if(!isNaN(item) {
    numberArray.push(item);
  }
});

console.log(letterArray, numberArray);
```

Comment: So do I make a loop first that goes through each item like this
     for (; L < splitResult.length; L++) {

and then replace each "item" in the code you provided with 

splitResult[L]?

Comment: No just replace the value for yourString with your "input" string and if its seperated with `,` just replace `yourString.split('')`  with `yourString.split(',')`

Comment: forEach ist lopping over your splitted string (which is an array now):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: My bad I copied and pasted code for that, splitResult was my already-split array

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is loop through the array, you can use the Array prototypes [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Or you can use the normal `for` loop to check through each element of the array. You can now check if each element `isNaN` and then push into the right array appropriately. You can use the snippet below

```
const yourArray = ['1','a','2','b','3','c','4','d'];
const letterArray = [];
const numberArray = [];
yourArray.forEach((eachItem) => {
  if(isNaN(eachItem)){
    letterArray.push(eachItem);
  } else {
    numberArray.push(eachItem);
  }
});

console.log(letterArray, numberArray);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input, but I don't know what to replace "eachItem" in the code you provided with

Comment: `eachItem` represents each value in the array. If you're using a `for` loop. You would have used `yourArray[index]`. The `forEach` method can take a function as it's parameter, and the first parameter specified in that function represents each item of the array. Check that link in the answer for more details

Comment: Okay so after using your example, I get two problems.

Comment: What were the problems?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to edit that post, but it told me my comment was too long, so I gave up and made a new question in the forum. Thanks for checking back, though; and sorry about that!